# Having troubles implement my app in an Object Oriented manner

Tags: javascript

I've been coding JS for a while, but I've never did anything object oriented. I usually just defined all my variables at the top, and then just used them all. I kept hearing over and over to use OO, but now I can't do what I want and I can't get any help.

Here is a fiddle, along with semi identical code:

http://jsfiddle.net/zDeAJ/1/

```
var App = {
    options: {

        /* ------------------------------------
             Options (PREFERABLY DONT CHANGE)
        --------------------------------------- */

        baseDomain     : 'google.com',
        apiVersion     : '/api/v1'

    },
    state: {

        current: App.options.baseDomain + App.options.apiVersion

    }
}
```

So doing App.options.baseDomain (or this.options.baseDomain) won't work for me. What's the usefulness of defining Application level variables if I can't define other application level values based on them? I know this is a vague question but I really don't know what I'm asking... I just have a problem in that what I was easily able to accomplish with just a bunch of variables that held not only settings, but state within my application, is not so easy with my knowledge of Javascript OO patterns.... 
​
Edit: Alright, this is specifically what I want to do:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4D4l.png

But I wasn't aware of the limitations... so I need a way around it, which sticks as close and elegant as possible to this implementation.

Comment: Using deeply nested properties of objects doesn't make your code object oriented.

Comment: I gave you a portion of my code... imagine App.options.baseDomain is this.options.baseDomain.. and is a constructor. To do that, I need to tackle this problem otherwise it's pointless to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of your approach as creating an "Instance" object called App.

Here's a slightly different approach.

```
function App () {
    // Save a reference to the object
    var that = this;

    that.options = {
        baseDomain: "google.com",
        apiVersion: "/api/v1"
    };

    that.state = {
        current: that.options.baseDomain + that.options.apiVersion
    };
}

var myApp = new App();
// Write the current state to the screen
document.write(myApp.state.current);
```

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zDeAJ/1/

Hope this helps!

Comment: I would like to still use an object if at all possible... check my question for updated details.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following (in JavaScript, functions are objects):

```
function App () {
    // Save a reference to the object
    this.options = {
        baseDomain: "google.com",
        apiVersion: "/api/v1"
    };

    this.state = {
        current: this.options.baseDomain + this.options.apiVersion
    };
}

var myApp = new App();
console.log(myApp);
```

Comment: Right but now I can no longer do this.options.baseDomain like I said in the comments... sorry, check my image I added to the question for further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite generic; you should be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish.

That aside, read the documentation on objects;

Taken from [w3schools:](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)

> With JavaScript you can define and create your own objects.
>
> There are 2 different ways to create a new object:
>
> ```
> 1. Define and create a direct instance of an object.
> 2. Use a function to define an object, then create new object instances.
> ```

Way 1:

```
personObj=new Object();
personObj.firstname="John";
personObj.lastname="Doe";
personObj.age=50;
personObj.eyecolor="blue";
```

Way 2:

```
function person(firstname,lastname,age,eyecolor)
{
    this.firstname=firstname;
    this.lastname=lastname;
    this.age=age;
    this.eyecolor=eyecolor;

    this.changeName=changeName;
    function changeName(name) {
        this.lastname=name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check my original question for a picture of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is an interpreted language. That means your code is evaluated from the inside out or the most inner expression is evaluated and passed to the next outer expression.

In your example the value of `options` get's evaluated first and next the value of `state`. The problem is that you can't access the associative array of `App` before it is fully evaluated, wich is not the case during the evaluation of the value of `state`.

`EDITED`

Sorry for not answering correctly. Here is a refined approach from your second:

```
var App = {
    options: {

        /* ------------------------------------
             Options (PREFERABLY DONT CHANGE)
        --------------------------------------- */

        baseDomain     : 'google.com',
        apiVersion     : '/api/v1',
        blah: ''

    },
    blah: function(){

        return App.options.baseDomain + App.options.apiVersion;

    }
}

console.log(App.blah());
```

Comment: I guess so, but I want to know an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Not one of you answered my question.... I thought about it a little... I could use a named function inside of the literal to access it... and if I wanted (not necessary) I could even assign it back to the options object

http://jsfiddle.net/zDeAJ/9/

```
var App = {
    options: {

        /* ------------------------------------
             Options (PREFERABLY DONT CHANGE)
        --------------------------------------- */

        baseDomain     : 'google.com',
        apiVersion     : '/api/v1',
        blah: ''

    },
    state: function(){

        this.options.blah = this.options.baseDomain + this.options.apiVersion;

    }
}

App.state();
console.log(App.options.blah);
```

​